# Can I use an object in UriTemplate?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I tried the following code:

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(UriTemplate="/Users/Register/{user}")]
 void Register(User user);
```

But when I Try to run this, it tells me the UriTemplate must only contain strings.  What if I need to pass in an object to my method as in this case, a User object to my Register method.

If I change the WebInvoke attribute to:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate="/Users/Register/")]
```

The browswer displays the error `Method not allow` when I try to browse to http://localhost:8000/Users/Register for example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are limited to strings in the UriTemplate. You could use multiple parameters to pass multiple strings but you cannot use a complex type. If you want to pass a complex type, then it cannot be anywhere in the URI but rather in the body of a POST/PUT request. The GET request does not take a message body.  So your above code could be changed to this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate="/Users/Register")]
void Register(User user);
```

Where you're passing the User object in, not via the Uri, but as part of the POST request.

Comment: Thanks, Can you elaborate on what you mean by part of the POST request?  I actually tried what you mentioned before, that is just having /Users/Register in my UriTemplate, but then when I navigated to http://localhost:8000/Users/Register, it said Method not allowed.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you "navigated" to the URL? You just hit it in a browser? If so, that did a GET request which is not allowed when you use the [WebInvoke] attribute (you need to use [WebGet] for that). [WebInvoke] is for POST/PUT/DELETE (you'll see I specified "POST") in my code example above. check out: http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/olt/howtovideos.aspx?category=WCF%20REST

Comment: oh duh, you are right about that.  The basis of all this is that a user will go to a sign up page, fill in some fields and register. The Register part will be handled by a POST.  I can probably handle that on a button click, right? But what is to prevent someone from going to http://localhost:8000/Users/Register?

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly as it says. A URI is literally only capable of containing strings. They aren't made for objects. You could probably convert it to take a user name or user id instead if you needed... but you can never use a complex object type as a URI.

Comment: In this case, I don't have a UserId yet because I need to first create the User.

Comment: I was going to create the user in the Register method.  Maybe that is bad design?

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass objects around as query string parameters (how could you?  would it serialize it somehow?)  You should pass in the user id.

Comment: See comments to Steve and md5sum